# kendo Tree List not refreshing when bind new data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, kendo-ui, tree

I have a DropDownList and kendo Tree List in asp.net mvc core. that i want to when DropDownList selected Changes tree view has been refreshed by new data.but refresh data not working:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(d => d.RoleId)
                            .DataSource(d=> d.Read(r=> r.Action("RoleList", "Role", new { }).Type(HttpVerbs.Post)))
                            .DataTextField("Name")
                            .DataValueField("id")
                            .Events(d => d.Change("winRolePermissionDetails.onChangeCat"))
                            )

winRolePermissionDetails = {
....
onChangeCat: function (e)
        {
            debugger;
            var id = $("#RoleId").val();
            if (id <= 0)
                return;

            $.ajax({
            url: "/RolePermissions/FormActionList/" + '?roleId=' + id,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            //data: {  roleId=id },
            success: function (result) { 
                   var tvProjeto = $('#tree_formActions').data("kendoTreeList");
                   tvProjeto.dataSource.data(result);
                   
                }
                
             });
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Any errors in the browser dev tools? Does the ajax network call happen, and does your success function get called? Please also include the config code for your treeview.

Comment: Try `tvProjeto.dataSource.read(result);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should pass your parameter to method 'read' of kendoTreeList,please delete ajax request box and insert this code instead of:

```
$('#tree_formActions').data("kendoTreeList").dataSource.read({roleId:id});
```